# How does CMAKE tell the makefile to link a library?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I have a simple executable that uses functions from a library **mylib** at `~/mylib/lib/libmylib.so`.

On `CMakeLists.txt`, I tell CMAKE where to find the library and link it:

```
find_library(MYLIB_PATH mylib HINT $ENV{HOME}/mylib/lib)
target_link_libraries (output "${MYLIB_PATH}")
```

after doing `cd build; cmake ..`, the **Makefile** is generated, and calling `make` *compiles it successfully.*

---

But let's say I comment the second line on `CMakeLists.txt`, as

```
find_library(MYLIB_PATH mylib HINT $ENV{HOME}/mylib/lib)
# target_link_libraries (output "${MYLIB_PATH}")
```

And perform the same `cd build; cmake ..`. **I get the exact same Makefile**, however `make` fails with these kinds of errors:

```
In function `Model::Model(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
Model.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `TF_NewStatus'
```

It makes sense that it fails because the library is not linked. But if both **Makefile**s are the same, why would one `make` fail and not the other?

Comment: Did you clean the directory the second time? Maybe CMakeCache.txt has something todo with it

Comment: How do you know you get "the exact same Makefile"? CMake will create multiple files for the build process, have you checked them all?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did `sdiff -s` between them and the result was empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every executable and library CMake creates `link.txt` script which performs the linking step.

This file is used in per-target `build.make` script via

```
$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/<target-name>.dir/link.txt
```

Comment: I always thought CMAKE would generate a simple, "independent" Makefile that would be used for compilation, but I just realized this file includes other files inside of `CMakeFiles/` folder, with many other hidden configurations.